# Drupal: How to share content between two Drupal sites?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, content-type

I have two drupal 7 sites and I want them to share content of a certain content type. I want to have this content stored in an external database. How could I make this happen with a custom module?

Comment: Did you try anything or are you just asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a Rest server.
Then you can use views to share the information you want.

Module: https://drupal.org/project/services

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a closer look on these modules:

[Drupal Sync](https://drupal.org/project/drupal_sync)

[Drupal Deploy](https://drupal.org/project/deploy)

I didn't try out one of these so far, but I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Contents (ie. nodes) on a Drupal site are not stored in a single tables. The same tables are used to store content of different content type. Some of the tables are created dynamically when you add fields to a content type, or when you change their settings. So you cannot share some contents between two sites by simply sharing the table(s) used to store them.

As a rule of thumb, you cannot achieve anything complexe in Drupal by simply doing stuff at the database level. There is too much storage logic implemented in (PHP) code that cannot be ignored when accessing the DB. You should always base your solution on Drupal's API (and most of the time, not the DB layer API, but the high-level API such as the Node and Fields APIs).

That said, there is no core API to communicate between sites. I would use one of the site as the canonical source of the shared contents and the only site where they can be edited. Then somehow replicate these content on the second site. This can be done with the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) or [RESTful Web Services](https://drupal.org/project/restws) module on the second site, and a custom module on the first site, used to push new contents and the updated contents to the second through a REST service.